# How to split by space-space in single call-Java

Tags: jsoup

I want to split the string with space and - (hyphen)-here having AND condition.

Sample Data:

```
Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India - ‎Chairperson-Centre for Continuing Education • Head-NI, BD & Marketing • Associate Dean-Skill Dev. at Mason UNIVERSITY - ‎Mason University
```

```
String[] arrDesignation = strArea.split(" - ");
```

Expected data:

> Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India
>
> ‎Chairperson Centre for Continuing Education • Head NI, BD & Marketing • Associate Dean Skill Dev. at Mason UNIVERSITY
>
> ‎Mason University

Actual data:

> Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India
>
> ‎Chairperson
>
> Centre for Continuing Education • Head
>
> NI, BD & Marketing • Associate Dean
>
> Skill Dev. at Mason UNIVERSITY
>
> ‎Mason University

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: He is using hyphen with spaces around (" - ") as separator, but the string gets split with hypen("-") only too.. This is the problem I guess.

Comment: I need to have a combination in a single call, as you can notice, Data under 0th position would be location, 1st position reflects designation and 2nd position reflects the name of the company and that phenomena are static. Expected length of the array is 3 but getting 5 or more.

Comment: Try `\s` instead of space (I cannot test it right now, but it might work).

Comment: I can't reproduce that in [ideone](https://ideone.com/bEt6YI) ... check that you don't `trim()` the pattern used in `String.split`... that would result in a split `"-"` that explain the output.

Comment: I applied below options:

Comment: @jackgu1988 I tried already, 
\\s, \\s+, \\s-+, \\s-\\s, \\s-\\s+

Comment: @AxelH I tried multiple combinations too.

Comment: provide a [mcve], include the JDK version you are using (who knows...) but as for the information I see, this is not a problem, this is working has expected (just check the linked posted before)

Comment: By the way, the expect result is removing the hyphen in `Chairperson Centre` ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161013/discussion-between-nimesh-prajapati-and-axelh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
      String input = "Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India - Chairperson-Centre for Continuing Education • Head-NI, BD & Marketing • Associate Dean-Skill Dev. at Mason UNIVERSITY - Mason University";

    String[] split = input.split("\\s-\\s");

    for (String s : split) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

I'm getting

```
Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India
Chairperson-Centre for Continuing Education • Head-NI, BD & Marketing • Associate Dean-Skill Dev. at Mason UNIVERSITY
Mason University
```

\s in regex refers to whitespace character

[regex whitespace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp)

Comment: Sorry I tried on a regex site, It was not working. But Java handles it correctly. This works.

Comment: @DogukanZengin ... JAVA need to escape \ so the regex is actually `\s-\s`

Comment: @AxelH Actually I considered that too but maybe I did something else wrong.

Comment: @DogukanZengin probably - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/suhoNW/1). Well this is still not explaining why the original solution is not working for OPs but is a valid solution.

Comment: @GuyKhmel- I tried your solution too but no success. I would like to admit-i'm using eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) with java9

Comment: @NimeshPrajapati - that's odd. I'm running on IntelliJ with Java8 on a mac. And the solution I wrote works for me.

Verify that the regex string **value** is "\s-\s"  (the two \\ is for string parsing only).
You could save the regex term in a separate variable and verify it by printing it.
In addition, I suggest you to copy the code snippet I added and paste here the results, that'll help understanding what's wrong

Comment: @GuyKhmel: Ubuntu 14

Comment: @GuyKhmel: Your solution even did not split the string at all.

Comment: @NimeshPrajapati .  [Code in JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler#&togetherjs=Onx1a2KMQc)

It seems to be working

Comment: Try running what I wrote in a test class and see how does this behaves.
If it does, try copying your own text to the input variable and try again

Comment: @GuyKhmel Your code works fine in Jdoodle only not in eclipse editor with my test data. My run time code having one special char which I found now but it was not purely visible.http://vanillajava.blogspot.in/2012/09/hidden-code.html
‎‎‎‎‎One unicode char \u200e. Now trying to find the solution for the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
String[] arrDesignation = strArea.split(".*(\\s+|\\-)");
```

Comment: I'm using java 9, Jsoup, Spring boot 1.9. Still not working.